# How to force not to change (count) page numbers?

Tags: page-numbering

I would like a short solution to fix pagenumbers in a range (every page has the same pagenumber in that range).

Comment: Are you using [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)? Is that range at the end of the document, or perhaps in the middle?

Comment: And how should it continue? Say, it stops and page `n` for total of `p` pages. When it continues, should it show `n+p` or `n+1`?

Comment: I would like something like this: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,20,21,22,23

Comment: Sorry, more precisely 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,10,11,10,11,10,11,10,11,20,21,22,23

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the page numbers to remain fixed, I would use two different page styles. The `regular` page style will be virtually duplicated for the `fixedpage` page style, except for `\thepage`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paper=a6paper]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}
\fancypagestyle{regular}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{.4pt}% Footer rule
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}% Footer
}
\fancypagestyle{fixedpage}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{.4pt}% Footer rule
  \fancyfoot[C]{\fixedpagenumber}}% Footer
\newcommand{\fixedpagenumber}{}
\pagestyle{regular}
\begin{document}
\section{First section}\label{sec:first}
Jump to section~\ref{sec:second} or~\ref{sec:third}.
\lipsum[1-19]

\section{Second section}\label{sec:second}
\edef\fixedpagenumber{\arabic{page}}% Store the current page number
\pagestyle{fixedpage}% Change page style
Jump to section~\ref{sec:first} or~\ref{sec:third}.
\lipsum[20-35]

\section{Third section}\label{sec:third}
\pagestyle{regular}% Restore page style
Jump to section~\ref{sec:first} or~\ref{sec:second}.
\lipsum[36-50]
\end{document}
```

The above MWE has pages numbered

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
```

For oscillating page numbers I would use a similar technique, but is a conditional to set the page numbers in the `fixedpage` page style:

```
%...
\fancypagestyle{fixedpage}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{.4pt}% Footer rule
  \fancyfoot[C]{\ifodd\value{page}\fixedpagenumber\else\number\numexpr\fixedpagenumber-1\relax\fi}}% Footer
%...
```

The above MWE has pages numbered

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 10 11 10 11 10 11 10 11 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
```

Both of the above techniques work with [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref).